# Is there a natural way to determine a threshold for required number of data points?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

Often you want to compute a statistic, but only for entities that meet criteria for having a meaningful sample size. For instance, in baseball you often see a footnote like "among batters with at least 100 at bats". A player might have one at bat, get a hit, and have a perfect batting average, but we don't want to include these hitters because the number of data points makes this hitter non-representative.

But that choice of 100 at bats for the threshold often seems arbitrary. Is there a way to let the data yield its own optimal threshold value? This would be a procedure that naturally fits the data set with a line separating the players with enough data points from the ones without, based on the relevant metric (e.g. batting average) in the data set itself.

Comment: I think this is a great question, but you need to be more specific: (1) what do you want to do with the data in the end? Compare means, or maxima, or minima between the players? (2) What kind of distribution are we talking about here with respect to the events? Is it binomial (i.e., only hits and no-hits are counted)? Or are distances also relevant?

Comment: @JeremiasK: You propose some very interesting enhancements, but for now I'm just thinking of very basic statistics. So I want to discard the low-data players, and of those who remain, I want to simply show them in descending order of batting average, and also know the mean and stddev of that set, and/or show some simple charts to illustrate the distribution. Batting average is by definition simply hit/no-hit, although it discards things like walks and sacrifices. There are more sophisticated measures of performance, but I'm not worried about that issue for now.